# Constant and restrictions in Weil's bound for sum of character from polynomial over interval

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, algebraic-number-theory, upper-lower-bounds

I found in a few papers (eg. here: [Burgess](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/plms/s3-13.1.537/abstract)) a note which states

> It is a well-known consequence of the theorem, due to Weil [...] then $\sum_{x=N+1}^{N+H} \chi(f(x)) \ll p^{1/2}\log{p}$

However, I couldn't find neither what are the restrictions on $N$ and $H$, nor what is the exact value of the best known constant for polynomials of degree $d$. Since $\sum_{x=0}^{p-1} \left( \frac{x^2 + 1}{p} \right) = -1$, there must me some restrictions on $N$ and $H$, because otherwise we could sum from $0$ to $Kp$ and get in result $-K$ for arbitrary huge $K$, which would contradict with the theorem.
And unfortunately I don't know french (and to be honest my knowledge about algebra is too minuscule) to understand the Weil's original paper.

So my question is

> What are the constraints on $N$ and $H$ and what is the best known constant for polynomials of degree $d$?

Comment: I guess this asymptotic bound holds as p grows; so you can't keep p constant and let H grow.

Comment: I agree. However, Burgess wrote that this constant depends on the degree of $f$, which I understood as "this constant depends ONLY on the degree", which is the case for $f(x) = x$ ( http://iml.univ-mrs.fr/~ramare/TME-EMT/Articles/Art15.html )